# How should my script refer to a character who's currently disguised as another character?

Tags: characters, dialogue, scriptwriting

I've recently resumed writing a series of scripts for an anime I've been planning. One of the characters has the ability to shape-shift, and there are several scenes in which she initially appears disguised as another character, before shape-shifting back into her normal self.

So far, when writing these scenes, I've referred to the character using the name of the person she's disguised as, and only switched back to her real name after she transforms back again. However, the top answers to [these](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/52704/23927) [questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/50806/23927) suggest that I shouldn't do that; scripts are production documents, and it's imperative that the crew know exactly who's supposed to be in each scene, hence I should always refer to characters by their real names.

But in the case of a character who's disguised as another character, **how do I do this while also making it clear that they're pretending to be someone else right now?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While in the process of typing up the question, I had a brainwave - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Pt.2* does the same thing, during the scene in which Hermione uses Polyjuice Potion to disguise herself as Bellatrix Lestrange. (The other Polyjuice Potion scenes from the previous films also count, but that was the one that sprang to mind.)

The [production script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/harry-potter-and-the-deathly-hollows-part-2-2011.pdf) for *Deathly Hallows Pt.2* (starting at the bottom of Page 25) refers to the disguised Hermione as `BELLATRIX (HERMIONE)` - who the character *appears* to be, followed by who they *actually* are in brackets. This is a very elegant approach, and the one I intend to use myself.